# "Two sum problem" - why not "sums"?

Tags: irregular-plurals

Why in the name "Two sum problem" there is "sum" and not "sums"?

Comment: For the same reason you go on a two mile hike and pay for your tea with a two pound coin.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a native speaker and that's the first time I came across such a rule. Could you find some description of it, or simply its name?

Comment: Like a million dollar question; not million dollars question

Comment: The rule is: Nouns in a noun compound are singular. Even though everybody buys shoes two at a time, they go to a *shoe store* to do it, not a *_shoes store_, which is ungrammatical (marked by a star).  You can get more detail at the duplicate question marked above.

Comment: ... The rule has exceptions (as most seem to). A nine days wonder.